# Pin configurator and database for bare metal embedded systems

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, hal, bare-metal

Exploring the best ways to architect, code and test the configuration of the many pins, of a bare metal embedded system (~80MHz, ~64kRAM). One facet of this code (/layer) I see as a tiny databasecor data structure, while another I see as exercising the pins (Outputs/Inputs) through a thin layer of abstraction using the database (via Set/Get).

Embedded bare metal system tools and techniques can seem to lag other computing areas. I would thus like to read, if available, other peoples experiences on this topic.

Topic 1: Manage (/configure) all pins in one location (/module) through the use of a data structure (/database).
Pins do not tend to change ‘mode’ often, if at all, after bootup.  It makes sense to me to have a file (/module) where ALL 64-100 pins (common for an embedded ARM uC) are configured with their respective port_name, pin_number, pull_direction, speed, pin_mode (in, out or analog), pin_function (UART, ADC, DAC, Comparator, etc…..). Finally a pin_ID could act as an identifier for each pin, or a pin name if you will.

Topic 2: A very small database suited to embedded bare metal applications. 
Manage all these pins via a database. For example all these pin can also have a pin_value at any given moment during runtime. I would like to write and read these pin_value changes from (/to) a data structure (/database).
Extending the above concept on pin configuration and pin_value storage, we would get virtual pins.
A virtual pin can behave similarly to a physical pin. It will have a pin_ID, pin_mode and pin_value. For example we have an uC that looks at zero crossings of a signal. Zero crossing detection can only change from zero to one and back i.e. a digital input. We could say this has a pin_ID of ZC_ID, a pin_mode of INPUT_MODE and a new pin type of pin_class of value CLASS_VIRTUAL_DIGITAL.

Topic 3: Interface into the database - a thin layer of abstraction.
Other modules of our application can access physical or virtual pin value changes though the database.
Our application should be able to read and write to physical or virtual pins with simple knowledge of the pin_ID. For example:

Get_Value(uint32_t pin_ID, uint32_t value)

Set_Value(uint32_t pin_ID, uint32_t value)

The underlying code then decides whether this pin_ID is a simple write/read to a gpio pin or to a virtual pin.
Similarly, in the modern connected world, I have a need to read and write to external devices or servers. I would like to use the same database interface to be able to do this. Ie A server sends a message with an updated value to the uC module, where the database get updated with the new value. Our application can then read the new value from the database.

Thanks

Comment: This might be a valid question had you not started _"Looking for a book or other online resources ..."_, which is explicitly off-topic.  Note also _low speed_ is not the same thing as _"slow"_.  I'd trust a well designed real-time system on a 80MHz processor to achieve microsecond order level deadlines more than I would a 1GHz application processor running Linux for example.  Although I am not sure I would trust it if I/O accesses were mediated through some sort of data base.

Comment: Something generic is unlikely since platforms differ widely - if you choose to go "bare-metal", then adding OS-like infrastructure seems to defeat the object.  How does this proposal differ from a device driver?

Comment: confused as  why you would such a library.   not only does the hardware vary but gpio is often multiplexed with special purpose I/O so even more chip specific.  the I/O is easy to manage per chip so why abstract it and add more code, make it slower, mess up the timing, etc, etc?

Comment: Because the hardware varies I want such a library. I thin layer like this will help with any future hardware changes wrt I2C-EEPROM or SPI_ADC, or I2C-Accelerometer chip changes, or even microcontroller changes. It will minimizes the impact on application related code that has been written so far. I see this a point worth exploring. I believe coding and testing ideas will improve the architecture. Yes microcontrollers are slow are far most computing devices go, which is why we are having this discussion. How can one add thin layer of abstraction on a bare metal device.

Answer (score 1):

***In the specific case of GPIO, the best idea is to have as little in the way of abstraction layers as possible***.

You need one function for setting up a port or pin and possibly some clock and pin routing setups. Port access should however preferably be done directly, by writing directly to the data registers. Why? Because if you make a HAL such as this:

```
pin_t pin_allocate (port, pin);
void pin_set (pin_t* p);
```

where `pin_t` is some abstract, opaque type, then you may run into very subtle re-entrancy bugs caused by the application programmer losing track of what's going on in the code.

Consider this situation:

```
// BAD DESIGN, don't do this

static pin_t* led;
statci pin_t* relay;

void main (void)
{
  led = pin_allocate(PORTA, 0);
  relay = pin_allocate(PORTA, 1);
  ...

  pin_set(led);  
}

...

void PORTA_ISR (void)
{
  pin_set(relay);
}
```

There is a race condition bug in this code but it is completely hidden away by abstraction layers.

- Some code has allocated a pin on the same port as is used to drive a relay. Is about to set the LED.
- The `pin_set()` likely stores the value of the port register and prepares to do a bitwise OR.
- ISR strikes. The port register is written to with the value to set the relay.
- Return from subroutine. The LED write to the port register is completed and the relay output is cleared.
- This will manifest itself as a rare, intermittent phenomenon where the relay fails to set and instead we experience a short glitch on the coil, too short to drive it.
- If the programmer eventually mistakes a race condition bug, they might start to investigate access to the `relay` variable. But that variable in itself might be protected and thread safe - the problem lies underneath the HAL.

I have seen the above scenario several times and it's one of the hardest bugs to find, all categories. So my advise is to not over-engineer this in software.

Instead keep track of pins through the **PCB schematic**, which is the normative document. Anyone writing code *has* to look at the schematic before they decide to use a certain pin, rather than just staring at their own software. Look for potential conflicts with other hardware, before you start to write any code.

In addition, GPIO might be realtime-critical and abstraction layers mean overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your response Lundin. I can see your point about the race condition between normal context and ISR. I will keep it in mind and assume isr_disable(), isr_enable() around a pin_set() will help mitigate such a problem. Some abstraction with regards to the various I/O operations (pin Set/Clear, pin Pulse, local(/virtual) variable Read/Write, remote variable R/W) seems logical. A unit testable layer for all developers to use seems a good approach.

Comment: @almost_linear "isr_disable" usually refers to the global interrupt mask and is therefore too crude. You could disable the local interrupt for a given port, but in that case you'd have a tight coupling between various parts of the code, which also speaks against abstraction layers.

Comment: I estimate 64 physical pin configurations along with around at least a dozen 'virtual' pins (temperature, humidity, pressure, button1, button2, current rms, voltage rms, battery voltage, reference voltage, zero crossing, motor state, etc....) for many uC applications. Also the physical interface though which you read and write these pins can be different. The physical pins are your gpio, your virtual pins like temperature sensor could be on I2C, your EEPROM calibration data can be over SPI, your humidiy can be external data from a server via ethernet.

Comment: @almost_linear Yeah and so it makes no sense at all to mix up things like I2C or SPI with GPIO. Each peripheral that is more complex than just plain GPIO needs its own driver - which in turn knows nothing about the rest of the application. The actual pins will be handled by hardware in most cases, so there's no need to treat I2C as some "virtual pin". That's not just over-engineering, it is wrong design.

Comment: My thoughts are that a programmer for example a dsp engineer working on some filter or fft has no need to know where some calibration parameters live for example. He just knows which pin_IDs correspond to what parameters he needs and uses the Get_Value() from the IO_Manager layer. That way if the location of his calibration data changes his application has no or minimal impact.

Comment: @almost_linear Think at what is "embedded" vs "desktop" or "App". Embedded means embedded, everything is targeted to that particular host (the board). The contrary of App, where an app is expected to run on many different devices (using java in the good cases). So you end up having smartphones powerful like computers, and running twice as slow. That is the perfect contrary of the "embedded" philosophy!

Comment: @almost_linear The digital filter or fft would be in a file of its own and know nothing at all about GPIO. It doesn't make sense to have a digital filter accessing pins - it's just an abstract algorithm.

Comment: @almost_linear Also, as a rule of thumb: whenever you find yourself naming source modules "manager" or "handler", that's often an indication that you aren't done with the design. Programmers tend to stuff unknowns into a "manager" when they start coding too early, before they have iterated through the program design a few times.

Comment: A good abstraction layer can provide synchronised and unsynchronised versions of its functions to help avoid this type of bug.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that some microcontroller families provide set/clear pin mechanisms in hardware that avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: @Lundin Since the hardware is not set and likely to change I am exploring the possibilities of an abstraction layer. That way if it does change the application hopefully wont be impacted much. At some point in the application code a decision has to be made and a pin exercised or a value communicated.  I would like that operation to happen via an abstraction layer rather than a direct hardware call. Yes, correct I unknowns, which is why I am exploring ways of mitigating these unknowns in a suitable way for a bare metal system.

Comment: I never see a case where GPIOs can be changed on the fly that mandates a need for a dynamic GPIO HAL since it is always dependent on the design on the I/O pins on the hardware. It is still a static one-time I/O configurations for a specific design, therefore having a GPIO database is quite unnecessary. Read/write access to an I/O port needs to take care of any interrupt activity on the same I/O port so we need to properly enable/disable interrupts on that I/O port. Probably, a database is useful for something like the I/O wizard in STMCubeMx to generate I/O assignments.

Answer (score 0):

> Topic 1: Manage (/configure) all pins in one location (/module) through the use of a data structure

This should be completely doable; actually, I (and other programmers I think) do exactly so: on system init, all the pins are configured from their default state (input) to input with pull-ups, or output, or associated to some special internal hardware (like an UART for example).

> Topic 2: A small database suited to embedded bare metal applications. Manage all these pins via a database. For example all these pin can also have a pin_value at any given moment during runtime. I would like to write and read these pin_value changes from (/to) a database. Extending the above concept on pin configuration and pin_value storage, we would get virtual pins.

Again this is doable, actually in a very simple manner. Sometimes I use a single integer in ram, where every bit reflects the status of a pin or other status. Interrupt handlers update those bits, and the foreground process looks at them. For output it's the same, reversed: the foreground writes these bits and an interrupt uses the bits to modify real pins.
So I end up with having two variables (input_statuses and output_statuses) that can be, for example, read and write remotely via serial, bluetooth or ethernet.

But from this point to a database, there is a great distance. Normally, embedded applications are near to the hardware without having too much virtualization, for the sake of performances and low cost. But who knows what are your requirements? Perhaps you have a big budget, powerful processors and little need for speed.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am targeting ARM cortex M0, M3 and M4. They are slow and very low on memory. However, I can see some obvious uC functionality that needs improving. I am convinced that other people have come across the same problem (/thoughts), especially in embedded Linux applications. It need not be a fully fledged database. Reining in the pin configuration, along with some simplistic data structure (/database) and the various I/O operations (pin Set/Clear, pin Pulse, local(/virtual) variable Read/Write, remote variable R/W).

Comment: Have you had some experience using GNU dbm? Could I port that to a bare metal system?

Comment: @almost_linear I have the impression you don't fully realize the picture, but I could be wrong. I would recommend to take a tour (i.e., use an MCU, write some embedded software), and then analyze again.

Comment: I just noticed GNU dbm requires a POSIX file system. Obviously that wont work for a bare metal application, but I think you get the general point about the use/need for a cut down database or basic data structure.

Comment: @almost_linear sorry, I get the point, ok, but I don't see the "need". Also I don't think ARM M3/M4 are "slow and very low on memory". They are what they are, because the market likes so. If you want to use a supercomputer to drive some GPIO, well, it's ok for you - but not for me I suppose!

Comment: Microcontrollers are slow compared to other computing devices. Never mentioned anything to do with supercomputers. Asking about a thin layer of abstraction and a data structure or small database suited to bare metal app.

Comment: @almost_linear the supercomputer was an ironic hyperbole. But the fact you said "arm m4 is slow and very low on memory" justified that hyperbole. I understand your point, but I suspect you don't know very well the whole picture. Anyway, best wishes for your project!

Comment: My experience tells me that hardware tends to change and affect lots of code that has been previously written. The only way I can see to mitigate this is to use a thin abstraction layer. From what I can see small databases suited to bare metal application are available that can complement this layer. The usefulness of such a layer needs to be evaluated. As far as I can conclude the general philosophy in the answers has been to write hardware dependent code which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

Arduino uses a simple system that works - at a very rudimentary level - somewhat along the lines you describe for Topic 1, albeit entirely at runtime (and it imposes no requirement that pin assignments are configured in a single location).

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd/tree/master/variants

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-samd/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.h

The table `g_APinDescription` serves as the database, and `pinMode()` and other functions manage the pin assignments.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Jeremy. Have you by any chance used LittleD (https://github.com/graemedouglas/LittleD)? How about ionDB? As far as I can tell there are small databases for bare metal application out there.

Comment: No I haven't.  And I agree with other commenters that the idea of using any kind of database (as opposed to a purpose-specific GPIO library) is really the wrong path to go down.

Comment: I will be using the low level drivers by STM. But i would rather not access the LL drivers directly from my application.